# How do we call this widget constituated of three horizontal dots?

Tags: html, angular

I want to search the Angular component name for this widget which is three dots, and when we click it then something like a context-menu appears:

[image]

How is it called?

Comment: it is a button with three dots as icon inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search here for that icon https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=dot&style=baseline.
[image]

And here you have some examples of creating this type of menu https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for, here is my code that works

```js
   <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon button with a horizontal three dot icon">
                                      <mat-icon>more_horiz</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                                        <button mat-menu-item>Edit</button>
                                        <button mat-menu-item>View</button>
                                        <button mat-menu-item>Delete</button>
                                    </mat-menu>
```

To change the three dot to be vertical, simple change this
more_horiz
to
more_vert